# echo last created table name from database . here i am not able to echo that name

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting warning --> mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean

```
enter code here
$db // database name
$sql1="SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND       TABLE_SCHEMA=".$db." order by create_time desc limit 1";
$res1 = mysql_query($sql1);
if($row = mysql_fetch_array($res1))
echo $row['TABLE_NAME'];
else echo "unable to fetch table name";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put quotes around the inclusion of the `$db` variable. Change this line:

```
$sql1="SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND       TABLE_SCHEMA=".$db." order by create_time desc limit 1";
```

To:

```
$sql1="SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND       TABLE_SCHEMA='".$db."' order by create_time desc limit 1";
```

Note that [mysql_* functions are **deprecated**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli_*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) with [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to avoid [security risks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) in your applications.

Comment: To make your answer more interesting for future visitors it would be good to explain the difference between the two lines (ie, the quoting of `$db`)

Comment: @fvu yes, you are right, sometimes I give long answers and explanations as on [here](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/76946/how-are-random-numbers-for-rsa-generated/76952#76952) but in this question it is just a syntaxic error. please, edidt my answer if you see there is something to explain better